# Multiple step registration form design

Tags: registration

I have a multiple step registration form. What is the trade off between what information is in the registration form and the profile?

For example should some content such as location be in the registration or should it be in the profile. Also "about us" should that be a profile field or should it be contained within the registration form?

The type of information that I am collecting are basic details such as username password, firstname, lastname, gender. And personal interest data such as books, videos

Comment: So you're asking whether the user should be required to input certain info at registration vs making it an optional field for the user's profile? What sort of information are you collecting and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The less information you ask in your registration, and the [later you require registration](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990711.html), the **more users will complete registration**. In addition, make sure users understand why you are asking for information. It is best if they have already used your site, and can see why you might need their location before you ask for it. If you ask for information before users know the benefit giving it provides them, they will [not fill it out](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/workflow.html).

So do your best to **minimize the required information**, and after you have them in your site and using your application, make it easy for them to provide the important (but optional) information later once they see the benefit to them.

Answer (score 6):

Limit the amount of information required for sign up. This information should include username/passwords, and anything that is necessary for an optimal experience (e.g. if it's a social site, there should be a step to find your friends).

After the user signs up, take them to their profile where they could fill out any optional information.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the fields this has huge impact on registration form conversion. Consider also using social login button i.e. Facebook and fetching some data from Facebook.

Check out more tips in [How to Optimize Registration Form for Higher Conversion](https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-optimize-registration-form-conversion-rate)